Electron density of states in 3D with phonons
Consider a semiconductor undergoing an indirect transition due to photon absorption (Equation 50, here). The density of states can be written as
$$
\rho(E)\propto \frac{m V^2 \int\left[\mathscr{E}_2\left(\mathbf{k}_2\right)+E \mp \hbar \omega\right] d \mathbf{k}_2}{16 \pi^5 \hbar^2}
$$
where $E$ is the input photon energy, $\hbar \omega$ is the phonon energy, $V$ is volume. In the neighborhood of the band's maximum, $k_m$ (with energy $e_2$), we make a parabolic assumption,
$$
\mathscr{E}_2\left(\mathbf{k}_2\right)=e_2+\frac{\hbar^2\left(k-k_m\right)^2 s(\theta, \varphi)} { 2 m_2{ }^*}
$$
where $m_{2}^*$ is the density of states mass and is chosen such that $\int s(\theta, \varphi) d \Omega / 4 \pi=1$, where $s(\theta, \varphi)$ denotes a possible angular dependence of the effective mass. The indirect threshold energy is given by $E_{i} = -e_{2}\pm \hbar \omega $.
The paper then states that the density of states may then be written as
$$
\rho(E) = \frac{\sqrt{2} m\left(m_2^*\right)^{\frac{3}{2}} V^2}{15 \pi^4 \hbar^5} \left(E-E_i\right)^{\frac{5}{2}} \\
$$
I cannot see how this step is achieved.

Attempt:
Substitute $\mathscr{E}_2$,
$$
\rho(E)\propto \frac{m V^2 \int\left[e_2+\frac{\hbar^2\left(k-k_m\right)^2 s(\theta, \varphi)} { 2 m_2{ }^*}+E \mp \hbar \omega\right] d \mathbf{k}_2}{16 \pi^5 \hbar^2} = \frac{m V^2 \int\left[\frac{\hbar^2\left(k-k_m\right)^2 s(\theta, \varphi)} { 2 m_2{ }^*}+E -E_{i} \right] d \mathbf{k}_2}{16 \pi^5 \hbar^2}
$$
But there is no way that this gives me the $5/2$ I'm looking for. If I try changing to spherical coordinates, I can get an extra $k^{2}$, which could give me $k^{5}$, then maybe concerting to energy would give me the $1/2$, but $E-E_{i}$ is already there, so that is unhelpful.  The volume of a paraboloid is $ V =\pi \int_0^h \frac{a^2 z}{h} d z =\frac{1}{2} \pi a^2 h$, but I can't see that helping either. I suspect it is obvious, for it being a 1 line explanation in the paper.

Shift the origin of the $\vec k_2$ integration variable to be exactly at the maximum value. This has the nice consequence that all your $k-k_m\to k$
I think the integration region of interest is not the entire 1BZ, but rather the tiny "spherical" region near the band maximum where the parabolic approximation to $\mathscr E_2$ is applicable. In particular, it should be such that the maximum $k_M$ that this integral goes up to, is defined by
$$\tag1\frac{\hslash^2k_M^2}{2m_2^*}=E-E_i$$
which implies that
$$\tag2k_M=\frac1\hslash\sqrt{2m_2^*(E-E_i)}$$
If you accept these, then the offending integral becomes
$$
\begin{align}
\tag3  \int\frac{\hslash^2k^2s(\vartheta,\varphi)}{2m_2^*}+E-E_i\,\mathrm d\vec k
     &=\int_0^{k_M}\left(\frac{\hslash^2k^2}{2m_2^*}+E-E_i\right)k^2\,\mathrm dk
       \int s(\vartheta,\varphi)\,\mathrm d\Omega\\
\tag4&=\left[\frac{\hslash^2}{2m_2^*}\frac{k_M^5}5+(E-E_i)\frac{k_M^3}3\right](4\pi)\\
\tag5&=4\pi(E-E_i)\left(\frac15+\frac13\right)k_M^3\\
\tag6&=\frac{64\pi\sqrt2(m_2^*)^{3/2}}{15\hslash^3}(E-E_i)^{5/2}
\end  {align}
$$
Which gets you everything that you are looking for, except for a horrible extra factor of 4.
Note that $E-E_i$ in the integrand is constant, and so replacing it with $(E-E_i)s(\vartheta,\varphi)$ gets you the exact same integral. I just couldn't be bothered with handling that detail at that stage.
